# Im trying to show my current location on a map but when I run my code in the simulator it doesn't work

Tags: swift, mapkit

// Here is some more info on the problem = Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate   {

    @IBOutlet var myMap : MKMapView!




    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()





        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        myMap.showsUserLocation = true            }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {



        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
    {
        print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }



    @IBAction func satelliteView(){
        myMap.mapType = MKMapType.Satellite
    }

    @IBAction func normalView(){

        myMap.mapType = MKMapType.Standard

    }


    @IBAction func pin(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        let location = sender.locationInView(self.myMap)
        let lCoord = self.myMap.convertPoint(location, toCoordinateFromView: self.myMap)

        let anno = MKPointAnnotation()

        anno.coordinate = lCoord
        anno.title = "store"
        anno.subtitle = "loctaion of Store"



        self.myMap.removeAnnotations(myMap.annotations)

            self.myMap.addAnnotation(anno)




    }



}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by doesn't work – otherwise it's hard to know how to help you.

Comment: When i runt the simulator it just shows a map of the world and doesn't point out my current location at all

Comment: You're ignoring what the location delegate sends you other than to print it, so that's why your current location doesn't show up. What does the `pin` function do when activated?

Comment: That is for dropping a pin for destination not for current location

Comment: That was not my question – what happens when you do push the control it is connected to?

Comment: It drops a pin where ever you tapped or clicked

Answer (score 2):

The simulator does not know your present location. Your need to let the simulator know your location.
In the simulator menu select `Debug > Location > Custom Location`

You can enter the `Lat` and `Long` of your physical location or any other location.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following is from an app I wrote. You need to call something similar when locationManager(manager:didUpdateLocations: is called

```
    func addPinAtCoordinate(latlong: Vector2D, plotting: Bool = defaultPlotState) {
        if self.plotting && !plotting {
            self.removeAnnotations(annotationStack)
            annotationStack = []
            self.plotting = plotting
        }

        let lat = latlong.x
        let lon = latlong.y > 180.0 ? latlong.y - 360.0 : latlong.y
        let coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
        let region = self.regionThatFits(MKCoordinateRegionMake(coord, MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: mapSpanDegrees, longitudeDelta: mapSpanDegrees)))
        if region.center.latitude != -180.0 || region.center.longitude != -180.0 {
            self.setRegion(region, animated: true)

            let note = MKPointAnnotation()
            let annotPoint = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
            note.coordinate = annotPoint
            self.addAnnotation(note)
            self.annotationStack.append(note)
            if annotationStack.count > annotationStackLength {
                self.removeAnnotation(annotationStack[0])
                annotationStack.removeAtIndex(0)
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog("Can't place invalid cordinate: ", latlong)
        }
    }
```

Most specifically useful relative to your problem are the lines  creating a region and calling setRegion.